# Memory Management in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-management

Consider the following:

```
    SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render0: function () {
            var view0 = new View0();
            view0.setElement("#right-block");
            view0.render();
        },
        render1: function(event) {
            var view1 = new View1();
            view1.setElement("#right-block");
            view1.render();
        },

    });
```

If I call `render0()` and then `render1`, what will happen to the object `view0`? Do I have to explicitly destroy the old view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `view0` will stay in memory as long as the `DOM` element `#right-block` exists. Because the event handlers on the DOM element is pointing to methods of your view, so it won't be garbage collected.

Ideally you should invoke `view0.remove()`, which will remove the element from `DOM` and also calls `stopListening()`.

But in your sample code, if you do that, the element `#right-block` will be removed from DOM, and `view1.setElement("#right-block");` won't work as expected.

In this case try invoking  `view0.undelegateEvents(); view0.stopListening();`, and if nothing else is referring to the view instance, it'll be garbage collected

Comment: Or override `View0#remove` to just `undelegateEvents` and `stopListening` if it is intended to be used with existing elements, that way you could always call `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to destroy the old view. Variables in objects that themselves go out of scope do not have to be manually cleared. When they go out of scope or when the parent object is deleted, the data contained within will also be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I understand. My concern is that even though they go out of scope after `render()`, they still seem to be not garbage collected as the views still operate.